# What is the derived set ( D(A) = ? ) in this example?

Tags: general-topology

Let X={a,b,c}, $\tau=\{{ \emptyset , X}\}$ and let $A \subseteq X$. Then find the derived set of A.

Comment: Look to the definition of derived set and limit points.

Comment: @Dave I don't know how to make use of them in this particular example.

Comment: @Neek I suggest to reformulate your question (click "edit") to make a more general one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  In the indiscrete topology, there is only one neighborhood for each point.

Comment: I already know that, $X$ is the neighborhood for each s $\in X $ but then what?

Comment: @Neek there are two cases: $A$ consists of one or more than points. Three if you also consider the empty set